# Javascript - Split a string separated by commas (best way)

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

> apple, banana, orange

and I want to get only the first word of that string and before the first comma:

In this example it's **apple**

For that, I have done the below:

```
var string = "apple, banana, orange";
var splitedArray = string.split(',');
console.log('This should show it ', splitedArray[0])
```

It works fine, but I am wondering if there exists a better way to it.

Comment: This way is absolutely fine.

Comment: `string.substring(0, string.indexOf(','))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of mapping the entire string into a array, you could just use `substring` togther with `indexOf`

```
var str = "apple, banana, orange";
var firstWord = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(','))
```

`substring` will take a part of your string fra indexA to indexB, and `indexOf` will give you the index of the first occurrence of a pattern (in this case a `,`).

I guess this approach would be faster since it does not need loop through the entire string

---

*substring*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

*indexOf*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Clean and neat, but I would like to understand more if you don't mind what's going on exactly also what about if I want to get `banana` with your approach, I believe it wouldn't work.. ?

Comment: @HamzaL.I have updated the answer. If you want to get the second item you could use the array-way (easy), or implement your own algoritmen for finding what you need (harder).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is how I would've done it, too. For short: `string.split(",")[0]`